# Convert MD5/SHA1 hash from binary to hex digest

Tags: perl, md5, hash

I am looking for a way to convert MD5 and SHA1 hashes from their binary to hex representations and vice versa. I want to do it in Perl but a common explaination is welcome too.

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
$data = "Plaintext";
$digest_bin = md5($data);
$digest_hex = md5_hex($data);
```

How can I compare `$digest_bin` and `$digest_hex` and make sure that they are hashes of the same `$data`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into the source of Digest::MD5::Perl, which is the pure perl version of Digest::MD5, you'll see:

```
sub _encode_hex { unpack 'H*', $_[0] }    
sub md5_hex { _encode_hex &md5 }
```

So you can do:

```
if ($digest_hex eq unpack 'H*', $digest_bin) {
    # same data
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. +1 for quoting source of Digest::MD5::Perl.

Answer (score 10):

```
unpack("H*", md5($x)) eq md5_hex($x); 
pack("H*", md5_hex($x)) eq md5($x);
```

[perldoc -f pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

The "H*" argument is used to translate a string of bytes into their hex representation and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
say "digest_hex: $digest_hex;
say "digest_bin (as hex): ", unpack("H*", $digest_bin);
```